# How does the Model-View-Controller pattern apply to iPhone development?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, model-view-controller

Recently I've been reading up on the MVC pattern and wish to apply it to my iPhone development. However, there seem to be so many variations of the pattern that I'm not sure exactly how it should be applied.

As far as I gather, the view will notify the controller of any actions which have been performed and the controller will in turn update the data model (if required). The data model will notify the view whenever a change to the data occurs and the view then updates it's display of the data appropriately.

In this basic model, the controller only has knowledge of the data model. However, I can't seem to figure out how to employ this design within my iPhone app.

The following page suggests an alternative version of the pattern where the controller has an awareness of both the data model and the view and all communication between the model and view is performed via the controller. It also seems to suggest that the model and view have access to the controller. Would I be right in suggesting that the data model interacts with the controller via some form of notification (notifications or KVO) and that the view interacts with the controller via actions?

Is this second model correct?

http://www.bogotobogo.com/DesignPatterns/mvc_model_view_controller_pattern.html

Many thanks,

Danny

Comment: Seems Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845951/discuss-on-mvc-implementation-on-iphone

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found Paul Hegartys explanation on MVC in iOS very helpful. [see his Stanford iTunes U video](http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/1-introduction-to-cocoa-touch/id395605774?i=87804048). MVC starts at minute 22.

**edit**
The link of the video doesn't bring you there as expected. it is **1. Introduction to Cocoa Touch, Objective-C, Tools, and MVC (September 21, 2010)**

Comment: I found this video very helpful and all the videos in that series... Must read

Comment: That video is indeed very helpful. Cheers for posting it! :)

Many thanks to all the other posters also. I feel that I have a much better understanding now.

Answer (score 2):

MVC has been around for a long time so there are many variations (or misquotes) to the pattern. Although, the concepts are much the same for most MVC implementations I have seen.

I would focus on how Apple defines MVC. Which can be found in the [Cocoa Design Patterns](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html) guide and from sample code downloaded from the SDK site (MVCNetworking example).

With iOS you will often will have Models and ViewControllers(which are a merged role of both the controller and the view).

Also, Martin Fowler has some great MVC stuff in his [GUI Architectures](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html).

Answer (score 1):

iOS development is very much orientated towards the MVC pattern.

It is usually done with viewControllers and a model. The view is build in Interface Builder, assigned to the controller and the model part is retrieved from elsewhere.

I would say that for Cocoa-Touch the second "version" of the pattern is the one that best describes what usually goes on.

The idea behind MVC is that the model and the view is reusable, but the controller is often fitted to the problem at hand.
This is also true for iOS development, especially if you use interface builder.

The view is hooked up to the viewController via actions/delegates and the model either broadcast its changes through KVO notification or by the controller pulling new data.

There is tons of code available from Apples developer portal and you should start out by looking at some of that code. Having your eyes and mind tuned to looking for the MVC pattern you will see they use it constantly, with the delegate pattern on top to provide event better abstraction

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, second one is better. Model and view should be separated completely. If view receives notification from model, the view will **depends** on design of model. By placing controller here, tightly coupled circular-dependency created.
Finally, each part cannot be developed independently, divide-and-conquer strategy is just impossible to use.

My advise for general cases:

- Make view and model passive and independent as much as possible. Major mutation must be done with only external manipulation. It should not be changed actively.
- Make controller actively controls both of them and other controllers.

In iOS, a UIView is a view which is fully passive. In most cases, all major mutation always done externally by UViewController. And model part should be implemented yourself completely as you want. (Or you can integrate models into controller if it's small enough, however, I don't recommend it)

In some big featured UIView, a sub-scale MVC patterns are used. Fractal!